# Submitting a non-english app to Marketplace, assembly information

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've made a Norwegian app. And in the Assembly Information -> Neutral Language I set the property to "Norwegian", default is "English (United States)". But when I tried to submit, I got an error, during the upload of the xap file. It said something about server error (don't remember exactly what more it said). Then I googled the error, and found a blog post of someone with the same error, and he said that the Neutral Language had to be set to "English (United States). So I did this, and the submission went fine.

However, now I see in the "details" of my submitted app, that the Language field is "English". And I'm wondering, will this be a problem for my Norwegian app? All text in the app is in Norwegian.

If this is a problem, what can I now do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you localized your application for both English and Norwegian, you should set the Neutral Language to English. And by English, I mean `en`, not `en-US`. The former is `English (International)` the latter is `English (US)`.

However, if you only have Norwegian, set the Neutral Language to `no`. Just be aware, that the application will only be approved for the Norwegian marketplace.

If you want the application to be in the international marketplace (or for several markets, so say, tourists also can use your application), you need a English localization as well.

The marketplace determines what supported languages you have, based on your Resources files. So you should have a invariant culture that matches your neutral language.

I'll personally recommend `en` as neutral language, and so ensure you have following resource files:

- Resources.resx
- Resources.no.resx

Then you'll get support for both a English and Norwegian description (and images, etc.) on the marketplace submission.

Comment: I have not localized for both English and Norwegian. It's just in Norwegian. It's a bit strange that it needs to be in English, not English US, because the default settings for a new project in Visual Studio is English US. You recommend that I add the 2 resource files (empty?) and then re-submit, to get the option of making both Norwegian and English description?

Comment: No, the default settings for a new project is English (en). The updated templates for 7.1 automatically add the NeutralLanguageAttribute with "en" as value. And yes, add the resource files, and re-submit. Even if they're empty, you still need them.

Comment: I cant' find an option to cancel the submission I've already made..hmm..When i start VS, new project and use the 7.1 templates, the default is English (United States). Just tried it

Comment: You can't cancel after it's been submitted. You can cancel up to the point where you press "submit" (last page). You can try do a demo app, and try it out. Also, try open the AssemblyInfo.cs, are you saying it says "en-US" in that? It does not on my computer.

Comment: Yes, i tried now, a new demo-app, 7.1 project, in the assembly.cs it says: [assembly: NeutralRescourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")]. But ok, I'll add the 2 resources files like you suggest, and then wait for the rejection or accept on the marketplace. Then delete it, and re-submit...sigh...Thank for your help Claus!

Comment: I'll encourage to change that to `en`. Odd, that my templates are different. I don't recall changing them.