# Can I make an app in my language?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've created an app, but I got rejected because of some language problems. What I did was that I've created an app in my own language.

So how can I pass the certification, as it must be possible to create an app to my marketplace in my language? It's content is dynamic so it makes no sence having an english translation. Possible steps:

- AssemblyInfo.cs
- - set `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("no")]` (my is "no"/"no-NO")
- Project settings (application)
- - add Your suported cultures (i have 5, Norwegian is hard :P)
- - deselected English
- Select only my marketplace (1, deselect 190 :D)
- Provide Norwegian store description
- Provide English description for the testers

Should make them happy right? If I try to upload the xap now I get the following:

```
3010: The [NeutralResourceLanguage] attribute is invalid on the entry assembly. Update the assembly and then try again.
```

So how can I successfully create a app for my own langauge and pass certification, I only want my app available in my marketplace?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about policies of some app store.

Comment: That said, a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601678/submitting-a-non-english-app-to-marketplace-assembly-information?rq=1

Comment: @Juhana wrong, Im asking what Im doing wrong as Im trying to push an app in my Language. There must be a setting telling someone my app is English?

Answer (score 0):

According to **How do I localize for a language that isn't supported?** section in following blog poost:

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/04/02/globalizing-and-localizing-a-windows-phone-app.aspx

You have to set as neutral a language which is a supported by the Store:

> Set your neutral language to one of the supported display languages. For example, 'English (United States)'.

In the description section, when uploading to the DevCenter, you  have to write a note in the neutral language saying that the app is actually in an unsupported languate, the description in the language (not supported) of the app and a description in the selected neutral language (supported). I.e. you don't only have to write a description in supported language for testers, but for everyone:

> On App Hub, you will be prompted to input metadata and a description for the neutral language you chose (for the above example, you'll be prompted for English). You must include the following three items in the 'Detailed description' field to pass certification:
>
> - A note, such as ‘The language of this application is [unsupported language name]’. This note must be written in the same language as the neutral language. For example, if you chose 'English (United States)' as your neutral language, the note must be written in English (United States). This note must be the first item in the ‘Detailed description’ field.
> - Your app description, in the same language as the neutral language.
> - Your app description, in the unsupported language.